# how to verify a coupon using django framework and sqlite?

Tags: python, html, django, sqlite

so, my basic idea is when a student enter a coupon provided by his educational institute the system should check if the coupon exists in the database or not and display a message saying the coupon is verified if it is in the data base, but what actually happens is an "errorList" message appears saying that the coupon already exits in the database and my customized message never appears

this is my views function

```
def apply_coupon(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ApplyCouponForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # code_entered = request.POST.get('code')
            code_entered = form.cleaned_data['code']
            coupon = Coupon.objects.filter(code = code_entered).first()
            is_available = True if coupon else False
            is_active = coupon.active if coupon else False
            if is_available and is_active:
                messages.info(request, 'Your coupon is verified!')
            else:
                messages.info(request, 'Your coupon is in valid!')
    else:
        form = ApplyCouponForm()
    return render(request, 'app/applyCoupon.html', {'form': form})
```

`is_available = Coupon.objects.get(code=code_entered).exists()` this line checks if the coupon exists in the databese

`is_active = Coupon.objects.get(active=True).exists()` this one checks if it is active or not

`if is_available & is_active:` i think this condition is never true but i don't know why

this is coupon model in models.py

```
# coupons model
class Coupon(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=50, unique=True)
    active = models.BooleanField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.code
```

this is my html template

```
{% extends 'base_layout.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div class="applyCoupon">
  <form class="applyCoupon_form" action="{% url 'app:applyCoupon' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="verify">
  </form>
</div>
{% if messages %}
<ul class="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}
    <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

this is the views function which i use to add a new coupon to the database

```
def addCoupon(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddCouponForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # save coupon to db
            form.save()
            messages.info(request, 'Your coupon has been saved successfully!')
    else:
        form = AddCouponForm()
    return render(request, 'app/addCoupon.html', {'form': form})
```

this is my form to add a coupon to db

```
# add coupon form
class AddCouponForm(forms.ModelForm):
    code = forms.CharField(max_length=4000)
    class Meta:
        model = Coupon
        fields = ('code', 'active')
```

and also this is my form to verify or validate a coupon

```
# apply coupon form
class ApplyCouponForm(forms.ModelForm):
    code = forms.CharField()
    class Meta:
        model = Coupon
        fields = ('code',)
```

i tried all the answers and it keeps showing this message on the browser
[a screen shot of my browser where my main problem is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/da8KW.png)
instead of the message i want which is this one `messages.info(request, 'Your coupon is verified!')`

if anything is not clear to you in my question please let me know and i will clarify it for you, i am just desperate

Comment: `is_active = Coupon.objects.get(active=True).exists()` this will be true if there are any active `Coupon` objects. You need to get a coupon, then check it: `current_coupon = Coupon.objects.get(code=current_code)`.  `if current_coupon.active ...`

Comment: Use is_available = Coupon.objects.filter(code=code_entered, active=True).first().exists(). You probably don't need is_active variable

Comment: @mobiusxs 
i tried your answer but it still gives me this message on the browser instead ``` Code: Coupon with this Code already exists. ```

Comment: @dishantmakwana
i tried your answer but it still gives me this message on the browser instead ``` Code: Coupon with this Code already exists. ```

Comment: Can you post your updated code?

Comment: @MarwaAbdElBasit Can you add `AddCouponForm`?

Comment: @dishantmakwana 
i updated my views function in the question

Comment: @Moha369
i posted ```AddCouponForm as you requested in my question

Comment: its clearly that the error is in the DB, you might need to migrate again. or check the db if there is any coupons with the same code.

Comment: @Moha369
actually the thing is i want to the user to enter a code and then click a verify button to check if the code he entered exist in the database, i don't want to enter a new coupon to the database i've already did this feature and it is working

Comment: Show us the full traceback so we can identify the error

Comment: @Moha369
there is no actual error in the cmd but it keeps showing this message on the browser (i updated my question and put a screen shot of the browser) instead of the message i want which is this one `messages.info(request, 'Your coupon is verified!')`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you will have better result by proceeding with an instance:
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
...

```
is_available=False
is_active=False
try:
    #create an instance if a coupon exists with the entired code
    coupon_instance= Coupon.objects.get(code=code_entered)
    is_available=True
    if coupon_instance.active:
        is_active=True
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
    is_available=False
    is_active=False

if is_available & is_active:
    messages.info(request, 'Your coupon is verified!')
else:
    messages.info(request, 'Your coupon is not verified!')
```

...

Comment: `DoesNotExist` is not defined, it must be `Coupon.DoesNotExist`.

Comment: Yep sorry it's ObjectDoesNotExist with the import to do...

Comment: @Renaud
i tried your answer but it still gives me this message on the browser instead ``` Code: Coupon with this Code already exists. ```

Answer (score 0):

Its because you're verifying `is_active` on the whole Table, the proper way to do this is:

```py
coupon = Coupon.objects.filter(code = code_entered).first()
is_available = True if coupon else False
is_active = coupon.active if coupon else False
```

`coupon = Coupon.objects.filter(code = code_entered).first()` retrieve a queryset and takes the first object in if it exists.

`is_available = True if coupon else False` checks coupon and assign `True` if there is something otherwise it sets it to `False`

`is_active = coupon.active if coupon else False` does the same thing as `is_available`, it retrieves the active attribute if there an object, and sets to `False` if there is nothing

Comment: i tried your answer but it still gives me this message on the browser instead 
```
Code:
Coupon with this Code already exists.
```

Comment: @MarwaAbdElBasit Already Exists is raised in case you're creating an object on a field that has `unique` attribute set to `True` and an object already used, its not raised from this answer because this answer is for calling coupons, not creating coupons. Post the code where you're creating coupons.

Comment: i edited my question and put my views function used to add a coupon to the database